# How to pass posted variables to an Anchor ID tag in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to insert some data into a table in DB, but the error came at where one of my fields is GET variable from the anchor tag.

To get a clear understanding please take a look at my code:

**index page:** with a post value of id = 1

```
<form name="user_form" method="post" action="input.php">

<?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM singleq ";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {                               
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $id = $row2['id'];
        $cat = $row2['cat'];
?>
<tr >

<input type="hidden" name="q_id" id="q_id" value="<?php echo ($row2["id"]); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="tablum" id="tablum" value="singleq" />
<input type="hidden" name="test_id" id="test_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" />
<td><a href='singleqbanksub.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>'><?php echo substr(($row2["question"]),0,100) ?>...</a></td>

<td><button class="button button1" type="submit" name="insert-data"  id="insert-data"  style="width:180px;">Add Question</button></td>
</tr> 

<?php     }
     } else {
    echo "";
        }
?>
</form>
```

**input.php :**

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php
$q_id = $_POST['q_id'];
$test_id = $_POST['test_id'];
$tablum = $_POST['tablum'];

$date = date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO english (cat, test_id, q_id, tablum)
VALUES ('$cat', '$test_id', '$q_id', '$tablum')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

header('Location: index.php?id='echo "$test_id";'');
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Here as I tried to pass the id through the anchor tag redirection to the same page to loop the process, it shows an error about an unidentified echo.

Comment: Where you found this error while i run anchor tag with pass value on my local host its working.

Comment: I found this as i gone through the input.php

Comment: so i hope the error not in this file , it could be in input.php file.

Comment: The code of input.php is also mentioned. please take a luk

Comment: You are using echo inside header.  Make it like this `header('Location: index.php?id='.$test_id);
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using echo inside header function which is wrong , use like this:

```
header('Location: index.php?id='.$test_id);
```

Comment: it works fine thanks but, as i came across a new problem of when index.php gets all columns from 'singleq' table and i try to insert one of them, irrespective of which one i select, only the bottom most of the column data is getting inserted..  do you know why is it happnening?

Comment: it happens because you are using last index value of fetched record.